# Has 32-bit QuickTime API and Quartz Composer file support changed in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-high-sierra, quicktime, quartz-composer

Has something happened recently to QuickTime API support for Quartz Composer files in macOS High Sierra?

I have a `QTZ` composition that opens fine in macOS 10.12, but fails to open in macOS 10.13. At the same time, it seems that QuickTime Player doesn't suffer from the same issue my code does, and can still open the `QTZ` files.

I have replicated this using the Objective-C API:

```
NSStrnig *path = @"/path/to/file.qtz";
NSError *error = nil;  
id movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:path error:&error];
```

… as well as (what we actually use in production) …

```
OSStatus status = NewMovieFromProperties(propertyCount, properties, 0, NULL, movie);
```

and in both cases I obtain an **error code -2048 : "noMovieFound"**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Quartz Composer 4.6.2 on macOS Mojave 10.14. At first I installed QC on macOS High Sierra 10.13 a year ago and in September 2018 installed Mojave over High Sierra (not clean install).

32-bit QuickTime API still works on macOS Mojave in QC. Even Apple Shake 4.1.1 compositing app (built on 32-bit Carbon API), that was discontinued on July 2009, still works here (macOS Mojave placed it in `/Incompatible Software/...` directory). And all my great old `QTZ` compositions can be opened in macOS 10.14. So, your error seems to be specific.